# I input Ctrl - D (EOF) when called scanf(), then next scanf ignored

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, eof

I input Ctrl - D (EOF) when called scanf(), then next scanf ignored.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int input;
   scanf("%d", &input);//I press Ctrl-D when this line
   scanf("%d", &input);//this line just passed. not read my input. why?
   return 0;

}
```

I want get input with scanf() second called.
What's is a problem?

Comment: What did you expect would happen - it would try to read past EOF?

Comment: @InternetAussie I don't want to read past EOF, I just read stdin.

Comment: @임근영 `EOF` stands for **E**nd **O**f **F**ile, i.e, the end of the input stream which implies that there is no more data to be read from the `stdin`.

Comment: "I don't want to read past EOF" It doesn't read past EOF so no problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that your code is OK. The only think is to remember to press "return" at the end of both input number. I rewrite your code in a "better" way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

int input1,input2;
printf("Digit the first number: ");
scanf("%i", &input1);//Press return at the end
printf("Digit the second number: ");
scanf("%i", &input2);//Press return at the end
printf("input1:%i\tinput2:%i\n",input1,input2);
return 0;
}
```